# Creating columns of differences faster in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I created the following data frame in R

```
c1 <- sample(10)
c2 <- sample(10)
c3 <- sample(10)
df1 <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)
```

I would like to create new data frame that takes the difference between the current row and previous row of the df1.

Of course, I can create it manually as following:

```
c4 <- df1$c1[2:nrow(df1)]-df1$c1[1:(nrow(df1)-1)]
c5 <- df1$c2[2:nrow(df1)]-df1$c2[1:(nrow(df1)-1)]
c6 <- df1$c3[2:nrow(df1)]-df1$c3[1:(nrow(df1)-1)]
df2 <- data.frame(c4, c5, c6)
```

but instead of having to define them one by one, I was wondering if there are more efficient ways of creating the columns.

Also, if there's a way, if I wanted to "select" certain columns to take difference, is there a fast way of doing so once I have the list of column names?

Comment: Just `df1[-1, ] - df1[-nrow(df1), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the columns, get the `lag` with  `shift` and subtract it from the original value.  We converted the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).

```
library(data.table)
setnames(setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) (x- shift(x))[-1])], paste0("c", 4:6))[]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_each(funs(. - lag(.))) %>%
    na.omit()
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
tail(df1,-1) - head(df1,-1)
```

Or another option is

```
sapply(df1, diff)
```

However, `diff` would be slower compared to subtracting directly or using the `shift` (as the OP's post concerns performance)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` and `apply` it for all columns

```
apply(df1, 2, diff)
```